# sierra changes both desktops when shifting using better touch tool

Tags: display, desktop, bettertouchtool

I use better touch tool to manage my desktop spaces. When I double swipe to change my desktop from on screen to another I want to do that just on one monitor (I have 2 monitors setup) but instead it just shifts both monitors desktops to the next one. How can I only do this on one screen?

Comment: What do you have set in System Prefs > Mission Control > Displays have separate Spaces ? Checked or unchecked?

Comment: gah!! i think that's totally it. checked now and i gotta log out. not sure how that got unchecked...do updates do that? so annoying

Comment: yup that fixed it!

Comment: I put is as an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure each display has independent monitor selection, make sure
System Prefs > Mission Control > Displays have separate Spaces
is checked.